# How do I request a single Spreadsheet with the C# GData API by Key?

Tags: c#, gdata-api

I have a program that authenticates and can fetch a list of all spreadsheets that uses version 3 of the C# implementation of the the GData API (it follows the [the example](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#retrieving_a_list_of_spreadsheets) found in the documentation).  What I am having a hard time figuring out is how to fetch a single resource by it's document key.  I can see plenty of examples of retrieving lists of documents in the [Google Documents List API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#searching_for_documents_and_files) and I can see how to zero into a specific document by an [exact name search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726209/spreadsheet-authentication-in-gdata-api), but I'm trying to produce some code that survives a Spreadsheet being renamed.  Here is the code I've written so far:

```
using System;
using Google.GData.Client;
using Google.GData.Spreadsheets;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;

namespace q14201622
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      //OAuth 2 Stuff
      var parameters = new OAuth2Parameters() {
        ClientId = CLIENT_ID,
        ClientSecret = CLIENT_SECRET,
        RedirectUri = REDIRECT_URI,
        Scope = SCOPE
      };
      Process.Start(OAuthUtil.CreateOAuth2AuthorizationUrl(parameters));
      var response = Interaction.InputBox("Enter oAuth Code:", "q14201622", "", 0, 0);
      parameters.AccessCode = response;
      OAuthUtil.GetAccessToken(parameters);
      var accessToken = parameters.AccessToken;

      //Fetch Documents
      var requestFactory = new GOAuth2RequestFactory(null, "q14201622-v1", parameters);
      var service = new SpreadsheetsService("q14201622-v1");
      var query = new SpreadsheetQuery();
      query.Title = "Exact Title";
      query.Exact = true;

      //Iterate over the results
      var feed = service.Query(query);
      foreach (var entry in feed.Entries)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(entry.Id + ":"+ entry.Title.Text);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not test this, but according to this https://developers.google.com/gdata/client-cs you can request a specific entry by using its URL :

```
FeedQuery singleQuery = new FeedQuery();
singleQuery.Uri = new Uri(newEntry.SelfUri.ToString()); 
AtomFeed newFeed = service.Query(singleQuery);
AtomEntry retrievedEntry = newFeed.Entries[0];
```

Now, if you have the document key, you also have the URL (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=[insert key here])
you can use a simple

```
string docKey = "nice doc key";
string  gDocsURL = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key={0}";
string docURL = String.Format(gDocsURL,docKey);
```

and then

```
FeedQuery singleQuery = new FeedQuery();
singleQuery.Uri = new Uri(docURL); 
AtomFeed newFeed = service.Query(singleQuery);
AtomEntry retrievedEntry = newFeed.Entries[0];
```

And you should be able to retrieve the doc.
If you want to save the doc to the HDD, simply add

```
string docFormat ="xlsx";// or xls or csv or pdf etc.
string gDocsDownloadURL="https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key={0}&exportFormat={1}"
string downloadUrl = String.format(gDocsDownloadURL,docKey,docFormat);
Stream stream = service.Query(new Uri(downloadUrl));
```

Comment: I'm working on testing this however the FeedQuery is not returning anything despite trying various permutations to the docsURL (I'm using a Google Apps instance so I tried the URL that my browser sees, as well as the URL from your example)

Comment: Hehe, then using your example, try searching for a file you know you have. Then simply console.write(entry.SelfUri.ToString()) and you got your self the proper url. Replace the url in the code above, and profit.... :)

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work either.  Calling `entry.SelfUri.ToString()` returns a URL like this: 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full/(KEY)' with a key that is shorter than the URL key found in the browser.  Passing that key to `singleQuery.Uri` returns an empty `feed.Entries`

Comment: The code is available at http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/source/browse/trunk/clients/cs/samples/spreadsheets/spreadsheetssampleapp.cs  If i am reading it right, they take all your worksheets using `SpreadsheetQuery query = new SpreadsheetQuery();` `service.Query(query)` then they are getting the URL by using `AtomLink worksheetsLink = entries[i].Links.FindService(GDataSpreadsheetsNameTable.WorksheetRel, 
                                                                       AtomLink.ATOM_TYPE);`.Check `worksheetsLink.HRef.Content` it contains the actual URL

Comment: This answer is clearly well researched and everything I can find points to it being correct.  I can only assume at this point that my trouble in getting it to work is the result of some other problem that I have not identified.

Comment: This example works perfectly when you import from your own account. , but it raises an exception for a public spreadsheet from another account. Is it possible to make it work fro any public spreadsheet?

Comment: @Dmytro Have you have success opening a public spreadsheet from another account?  I am running into the same exact problem.

Answer (score 2):

I have tested this against the Google.Apis.Drive.v2 Client Library nuget package version 1.9.2.1890. One thing to note, however, is that you are now required to register a developer's account with the Google API and setup API access and credentials for your application through the Google Developer's Console found [here](https://console.developers.google.com).

If you want to just use this for a service account aka not access files on behalf of the user but for automation or internal tools, use something like this:

(If I remember correctly service accounts still require a one-time OAuth approval interaction by a human via the OAuth browser pop-up to add the app to the authorized apps on the service account)

```
private const string SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = "YOUR_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL_HERE"; //looks like XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@developer.gserviceaccount.com;

static DriveService BuildServiceAccountService()
{
  var certificate = new X509Certificate2(PATH_TO_YOUR_X509_CERT,
      "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
  var credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
      new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
      {
          Scopes = new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive },
          User = "ACTUAL_EMAIL_ADDRESS" // this should be the normal xxxxxx@gmail account that has the google drive files
      }.FromCertificate(certificate));

  // Create the service.
  var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
  {
      HttpClientInitializer = credential,
      ApplicationName = "Drive API Service Account Sample",
  });

  return service;
}

public static void DownloadSpreadsheetAsXlsx(string spreadsheetName, string filePath)
{
  var service = BuildServiceAccountService();
  var request = service.Files.List();
  request.Q = String.Format("title = '{0}'", spreadsheetName);
  var files = request.Execute();
  var file = files.Items.FirstOrDefault();

  var dlUrl = String.Format("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{0}/export?format=xlsx&id={0}", file.Id);

  File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, service.HttpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(dlUrl).Result);
}
```

To access files on behalf of the user, you will need something like this to build your service instead:

```
static DriveService BuildUserAccountService(string userEmail)
{
  UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
  new ClientSecrets
  {
     ClientId = "YOUR_CLIENT_ID", // your client Id
     ClientSecret = "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET", // Your client secret
  },
  new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive },
  userEmail,
  CancellationToken.None).Result;

  // Create the service.
  var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
  {
      HttpClientInitializer = credential,
      ApplicationName = "Drive API User Account Sample",
  });

  return service;
}
```

**Old Answer for posterity's sake (The old Google GData APIs have been deprecated and anything below this point is no longer relevant and should not be expected to work):**

I was having the same problem with finding the document key. I ended up finding it in the AlternateUri. Here is what I did (this has been compiled and confirmed to work in a new project and adding GData.Spreadsheets with NuGet):

```
//Use your authentication method here:    
SpreadsheetsService service = new SpreadsheetsService("DownloadSpreadsheet");
service.setUserCredentials("your username", "your password");

SpreadsheetQuery query = new SpreadsheetQuery();
SpreadsheetFeed feed = service.Query(query);
SpreadsheetEntry fileEntry = feed.Entries.Cast<SpreadsheetEntry>().FirstOrDefault(entry => entry.Title.Text == "Name of spreadsheet");

//This is the good part
string key = fileEntry.AlternateUri.Content.Substring(fileEntry.AlternateUri.Content.IndexOf("?key="));
string dlUrl = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export" + key + "&exportFormat=xlsx&format=xlsx";
Stream stream = service.Query(new Uri(dlUrl));
using (FileStream fstream = new FileStream("something.xlsx", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
{
    stream.CopyTo(fstream);
    fstream.Flush();
}
```

I should mention that this requires LINQ (.NET Framework 3.5 or higher) due to the `.Cast<SpreadsheetEntry>().FirstOrDefault()` line. This can be done without LINQ, you will just need to manually enumerate the spreadsheets and find the one you're looking for instead of using a single line of code to do it. I just wanted to make sure everyone was aware before they started reporting that it does not work.

Comment: Using Service to download is an excellent way. The other way to download sheet is to build a URL and download using WebClient or other download means; but that would lead to a permission page by Google asking you to sign in first. This method by Josh doesn't ask that because Service has already authenticated the user.

Comment: Also you could add "&gridlines=false" to disable showing gridlines in case you're exporting as PDF format. By default Google shows the gridlines on your sheets in PDF.

Comment: I am facing same issue but for some reason your code is not working for me.It throws exception saying 'Execution resulted in a redirect from ..'

Comment: New API using OAuth2 ***https://console.developers.google.com/*** ? any full sample?

Comment: @Tweety01, did you figure a way to fix that problem?

Comment: @PreguntonCojoneroCabrónI updated the answer to work with OAuth2 and console.developers.google.com.

Comment: @Tweety01 The old example was using the GData API which has been deprecated for quite some time. I've updated the answer to use Google's new APIs.